# What not to test in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, testing

I've been writing tests for a while now and I'm starting to get the hang of things. But I've got some questions concerning how much test coverage is really necessary. The consensus seems pretty clear: more coverage is always better. But, from a beginner's perspective at least, I wonder if this is really true.

Take this totally vanilla controller action for example:

```
def create
  @event = Event.new(params[:event])
  if @event.save
    flash[:notice] = "Event successfully created."
    redirect_to events_path
  else
    render :action => 'new'
  end
end
```

Just the generated scaffolding. We're not doing anything unusual here. Why is it important to write controller tests for this action? After all, we didn't even write the code - the generator did the work for us. Unless there's a bug in rails, this code should be fine. It seems like testing this action is not all too different from testing, say, collection_select - and we wouldn't do that. Furthermore, assuming we're using cucumber, we should already have the basics covered (e.g. where it redirects).

The same could even be said for simple model methods. For example:

```
def full_name
  "#{first_name} #{last_name}"
end
```

Do we really need to write tests for such simple methods? If there's a syntax error, you'll catch it on page refresh. Likewise, cucumber would catch this so long as your features hit any page that called the full_name method. Obviously, we shouldn't be relying on cucumber for anything too complex. But does full_name really need a unit test?

You might say that because the code is simple the test will also be simple. So you might as well write a test since it's only going to take a minute. But it seems that writing essentially worthless tests can do more harm than good. For example, they clutter up your specs making it more difficult to focus on the complex tests that actually matter. Also, they take time to run (although probably not much).

But, like I said, I'm hardly an expert tester. I'm not necessarily advocating less test coverage. Rather, I'm looking for some expert advice. Is there actually a good reason to be writing such simple tests?

Comment: http://www.railway.at/articles/2008/05/14/do-we-really-need-controller-and-view-tests/

Comment: https://www.justinweiss.com/articles/how-much-testing-is-too-much/

Comment: https://signalvnoise.com/posts/3159-testing-like-the-tsa

Comment: http://codecrate.com/2014/11/rspec-controllers-best-practices.html

Comment: http://solnic.eu/2012/02/02/yes-you-should-write-controller-tests.html

Answer (score 11, accepted):

My experience in this is that you shouldn't waste your time writing tests for code that is trivial, ***unless*** you have a lot of complex stuff riding on the correctness of that triviality. I, for one, think that testing stuff like getters and setters is a total waste of time, but I'm sure that there'll be more than one coverage junkie out there who'll be willing to oppose me on this.

For me tests facilitate three things:

1. **They garantuee unbroken old functionality** If I can check that
   nothing new that I put in has broken
   my old things by running tests, it's
   a good thing.
2. **They make me feel secure when I rewrite old stuff** The code I
   refactor is very rarely the trivial
   one. If, however, I want to refactor
   untrivial code, having tests to
   ensure that my refactorings have not
   broken any behavior is a must.
3. **They are the documentation of my work** Untrivial code needs to be
   documented. If, however, you agree
   with me that comments in code is the
   work of the devil, having clear and
   concise unit tests that make you
   understand what the correct behavior
   of something is, is (again) a must.

Anything I'm sure I won't break, or that I feel is unnessecary to document, I simply don't waste time testing. Your generated controllers and model methods, then, I would say are all fine even without unit tests.

Answer (score 9):

The only absolute rule is that testing should be cost-efficient.

Any set of practical guidelines to achieve that will be controversial, but here are some advices to avoid tests that will be generally wasteful, or do more harm than good.

## Unit

- **Don't test private methods** directly, only assess their effects indirectly through the public methods that call them.
- **Don't test internal states**
- **Only test non-trivial methods**, where different contexts may get different results (calculations, concatenation, regexes, branches...)
- **Don't assess things you don't care about**, e.g. full copy on some message or useless parts of complex data structures returned by an API...
- **Stub all the things in unit tests**, they're called unit tests because you're only testing one class, not its collaborators. With stubs/spies, you test the messages you send them without testing their internal logic.
- **Consider private nested classes as private methods**

## Integration

- **Don't try to test all the combinations in integration tests.** That's what unit tests are for. Just test happy-paths or most common cases.
- **Don't use Cucumber unless you really BDD**
- **Integration tests don't always need to run in the browser.** To test more cases with less of a performance hit you can have some integration tests interact directly with model classes.
- **Don't test what you don't own.** Integration tests should expect third-party dependencies to do their job, but not substitute to their own test suite.

## Controller

- **In controller tests, only test controller logic**: Redirections, authentication, permissions, HTTP status. Stub the business logic. Consider filters, etc. like private methods in unit tests, tested through public controller actions only.

## Others

- **Don't write route tests**, except if you're writing an API, for the endpoints not already covered by integration tests.
- **Don't write view tests**. You should be able to change copy or HTML classes without breaking your tests. Just assess critical view elements as part of your in-browser integration tests.
- **Do test your client JS**, especially if it holds some application logic. All those rules also apply to JS tests.

Ignore any of those rules for business-critical stuff, or when something actually breaks (no-one wants to explain their boss/users why the same bug happened twice, that's why you should probably write at least regression tests when fixing a bug).

See more details on [that post](http://to-s.tk/what-not-to-test/).

Comment: "That post" - broken link.

Answer (score 6):

More coverage is better for code quality- but it costs more. There's a sliding scale here, if you're coding an artificial heart, you need more tests. The less you pay upfront, the more likely it is you'll pay later, maybe painfully.

In the example, full_name, why have you placed a space between, and ordered by first_name then last_name- does that matter? If you are later asked to sort by last name, is it ok to swap the order and add a comma? What if the last name is two words- will that additional space affect things?  Maybe you also have an xml feed someone else is parsing? If you're not sure what to test, for a simple undocumented function, maybe think about the functionality implied by the method name.

I would think your company's culture is important to consider too. If you're doing more than others, then you're really wasting time. Doesn't help to have a well tested footer, if the main content is buggy. Causing the main build or other developer's builds to break, would be worse though. Finding the balance is hard- unless one is the decider, spend some time reading the test code written by other team members.

Some people take the approach of testing the edge cases, and assume the main features will get worked out through usage. Considering getter/setters, I'd want a model class somewhere, that has a few tests on those methods, maybe test the database column type ranges. This at least tells me the network is ok, a database connection can be made, I have access to write to a table that exists, etc. Pages come and go, so don't consider a page load to be a substitute for an actual unit test. (A testing efficiency side note- if having automated testing based on the file update timestamp (autotest), that test wouldn't run, and you want to know asap)

I'd prefer to have better quality tests, rather than full coverage. But I'd also want an automated tool pointing out what isn't tested. If it's not tested, I assume it's broken. As you find failure, add tests, even if it's simple code.

If you are automating your testing, it doesn't matter how long it takes to run. You benefit every time that test code is run- at that point, you know a minimum of your code's functionality is working, and you get a sense of how reliable the tested functionality has been over time.

100% coverage shouldn't be your goal- good testing should be. It would be misleading to think a single test of a regular expression was accomplishing anything. I'd rather have no tests than one, because my automated coverage report reminds me the RE is unreliable.

Answer (score 5):

The primary benefit you would get from writing a unit test or two for this method would be regression testing. If, sometime in the future, something was changed that impacted this method negatively, you would be able to catch it.

Whether or not that's worth the effort is ultimately up to you.

The secondary benefit I can see by looking at it would be testing edge cases, like, what it should do if `last_name` is `""` or `nil`. That can reveal unexpected behavior.

(i.e. if `last_name` is `nil`, and `first_name` is `"John"`, you get `full_name` => `"John "`)

Again, the cost-vs-benefit is ultimately up to you.

Answer (score 1):

For generated code, no, there's no need to have test coverage there because, as you said, you didn't write it. If there's a problem, it's beyond the scope of the tests, which should be focused on your project. Likewise, you probably wouldn't need to explicitly test any libraries that you use.

For your particular method, it looks like that's the equivalent of a setter (it's been a bit since I've done Ruby on Rails) - testing that method would be testing the language features. If you were changing values or generating output, then you should have a test. But if you are just setting values or returning something with no computation or logic, I don't see the benefit to having tests cover those methods as if they are wrong, you should be able to detect the problem in a visual inspection or the problem is a language defect.

As far as the other methods, if you write them, you should probably have a test for them. In Test-Driven Development, this is essential as the tests for a particular method exist before the method does and you write methods to make the test pass. If you aren't writing your tests first, then you still get some benefit to have at least a simple test in place should this method ever change.